# How to add constant tensor in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

What I'm trying to do is to add a constant tensor to output of network:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(config.N_FRAMES_IN_SEQUENCE, config.IMAGE_H, config.IMAGE_W, config.N_CHANNELS))
cnn = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(config.IMAGE_H, config.IMAGE_W, config.N_CHANNELS))
x = TimeDistributed(cnn)(inputs)
x = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(x)
x = LSTM(256)(x)
x = Dense(config.N_LANDMARKS * 2, activation='linear')(x)

mean_landmarks = np.array(config.MEAN_LANDMARKS, np.float32)
mean_landmarks = mean_landmarks.flatten()
mean_landmarks_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(mean_landmarks)
x = x + mean_landmarks_tf

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
optimizer = Adadelta()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mae')
```

But I get error:

```
ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("add:0", shape=(?, 136), dtype=float32)
```

It's trivial in tensorflow, but how to do it in Keras?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems it can be done with Lamda layer:

```
from keras.layers import Lambda

def add_mean_landmarks(x):
    mean_landmarks = np.array(config.MEAN_LANDMARKS, np.float32)
    mean_landmarks = mean_landmarks.flatten()
    mean_landmarks_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(mean_landmarks)
    x = x + mean_landmarks_tf
    return x


x = Lambda(add_mean_landmarks)(x)
```

Comment: Just a heads up: Lambda layers migh lead to problems when the model is serialized and loaded with another python version. Keras custom layers are to be preferred. See: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9595

Answer (score -1):

In addition to your own answer, I would heavily favor a native implementation of addition, as for example [Keras provides `Keras.layers.Add`](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#add).

The reason for this is that I am unsure how your own lambda function is pushed down to the lower layers: Essentially, in TensorFlow (or whatever other backend you use), the internal operations make use of the heavily optimized computational graph, whereas custom operations tend to be translated to a heavier-weight (or, in the worst case, bloated) low level execution.

The correct way to do it with `Keras.layers.Add` would be simply doing

```
x = keras.layers.Add()([x, add_mean_landmarks])
```

Comment: If I just put `x = keras.layers.add()([x, add_mean_landmarks])` line I get `TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'`

Comment: My bad, I just noticed a spelling mistake in that line. It should either be `Keras.layers.Add()([x, add_mean_landmarks])` (notice the capital A here), or (I haven't tested this, but please follow the first link to look for yourself) `Keras.layers.add([x, add_mean_landmarks])`

Comment: Second argument is not a tensor : `ValueError: Layer add_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'function'>. Full input: [<tf.Tensor 'dense_1/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 136) dtype=float32>, <function add_mean_landmarks at 0x1064cca60>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.`.

Comment: `x = keras.layers.Add()([x, mean_landmarks_tf])` is also gives an error `node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'`