# Can't save Keras model when using reduce_mean in the model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The Keras code snippet reads:

```
second_input = inputs_d['second_input']
selected = embedding_layer(second_input)
item_average = tf.reduce_mean(selected, axis=1, keepdims=True)
second_input_encoded = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((3,))(item_average)
```

If I change second_input as from shape(5,) to shape (1,) and get rid of `reduce_mean` the code runs just fine.

The error message reads:

> /site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/serialization.py", line 69, in
>   get_json_type
>       raise TypeError('Not JSON Serializable:', obj) TypeError: ('Not JSON Serializable:',
>   b"\n\x04Mean\x12\x04Mean\x1a'embedding_1/embedding_lookup/Identity_2\x1a\x16Mean/reduction_indices*\x07\n\x01T\x12\x020\x01*\n\n\x04Tidx\x12\x020\x03*\x0f\n\tkeep_dims\x12\x02(\x01")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `Lambda` layer to perform custom operations:

```
item_average = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=1, keepdims=True))(selected)
```

The output of Keras layers are TF Tensors, but augmented with some additional Keras-specific attributes which is needed for constructing the model. When you directly use `tf.reduce_mean`, its output would be a Tensor without those additional attributes. However, when you do the same operation inside a `Lambda` layer, those additional attributes will be added and therefore everything would work properly.

Comment: this fails when saving model as h5. When loading back in, it complains about tf.

Comment: @Anton If it complains about `tf.reduce_mean` as not defined, use `custom_objects` argument when loading the model and pass `tf.reduce_mean`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52845882/2099607).

Comment: Saw that, but a weird duct tape solution, don't you think?

Comment: I found that you can fix tf import by using K.mean instead of tf.reduce_mean

Comment: @Anton Indeed, you can use `K.mean` instead of `tf.reduce_mean` and it would work. I used `tf.reduce_mean` because the OP used it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Objects that start with capitals inside the keras.layers module, such as Dense, LSTM.... , are layers which follow the convention of `Layer(...)(input)`, whereas lowercase are applied directly to tensors. Useful *inside* of [custom loss functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43821374/7760431) or custom layers  (like Lambda or [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55865378/7760431)).