# How to build this custom layer in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm building a NN that supports complex numbers. Currently working on complex activation. According to a Benjio paper, this is a good one:

[image]

**Where b is a trainable parameter to be learnt**. So I'm building a special layer to do this activation. I'm new to Keras and stuck already. I created this code below, but it gives an error with the build function. I have no idea what's happening, I just tried to copy the template. Please help.

```
class modrelu(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(modrelu, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        self.b= K.variable(value=np.random.rand()-0.5, dtype='float64')
        super(modrelu, self).build()  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        assert isinstance(x, list)
        ip_r, ip_i = x
        comp= tf.complex(ip_r, ip_i ) 
        ABS= tf.math.abs(comp)
        ANG= tf.math.angle(comp)

        ABS= K.relu( self.b + ABS) 

        op_r=  ABS * K.sin(angle) #K.dot ??
        op_i= ABS * K.cos(angle)
        return [op_r, op_i]

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        assert isinstance(input_shape, list)
        shape_a, shape_b = input_shape
        return [shape_a, shape_b]
```

Comments on my code:
In the **init** I didn't add anything, cause it is an activation layer that takes no input when instantiated.

In the build method, I tried to add the b's. Not sure if I should use the self.add_weight method. Ideally, I want to have as many b's as the dimension of input.

In the call method, this one, I'm pretty sure what I'm doing. It is easy, I just implemented the function.

The last one, compute_output_shape, I just copied-pasted the template. The output should be the same as the input, cause it is just an activation layer.

Finally, the error for what its worth, I know it is nonsense

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-3101a9226da5> in <module>
      1 a=K.variable(np.array([1,2]))
      2 b=K.variable(np.array([3,4]))
----> 3 act([a,b])

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    429                                          'You can build it manually via: '
    430                                          '`layer.build(batch_input_shape)`')
--> 431                 self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))
    432                 self.built = True
    433 

TypeError: build() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: can you post the error with the backtrace?

Comment: Sure, I just added it to the question.

Comment: comment on how I got the error. No error when I defined. No error when I instantiated the class. I got the error when I called the layer and gave it some input tensor.

Comment: may I see how you are calling the custom layer?

Comment: activation= modrelu();
a=K.variable(np.array([1,2]));
b=K.variable(np.array([3,4]));
activation([a,b]);

Comment: You need a `input_shape` to pass parameters in `build`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

First of all I should address the error you get from interpreter:

```
TypeError: build() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

The `build` method should take `input_shape` argument. Therefore you should declare build method as `build(self, input_shape)`

The second issue is undefined shape of the variables in the `build` method. You should explicitly declare shape of the variables. In your case the `np.random.rand` array should be of `input_shape` shape.

Another issue is that you are trying to return 2 results (`[op_r, op_i]`) in the `call` method. I'm not specialist in Keras but as far as I know you can't do it. Every Keras layer should have one and only one output. See here for the details: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3061

However if you use tensorflow backend you may use complex numbers (`tf.complex`) to return both real (`op_r`) and imagenary (`op_i`) parts of the complex number.

Here is the working implementation of `modrelu` layer with simple usage example. It is writtern for TensorFlow 1.12.0 which is distributed with it's own implementation of Keras API but I think you can easily adopt it for original Keras:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import Layer
import numpy as np


class modrelu(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(modrelu, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    # provide input_shape argument in the build method
    def build(self, input_shape):
        # You should pass shape for your variable
        self.b= K.variable(value=np.random.rand(*input_shape)-0.5,
                           dtype='float32')
        super(modrelu, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        assert inputs.dtype == tf.complex64

        ip_r = tf.math.real(inputs)
        ip_i = tf.math.imag(inputs)

        comp = tf.complex(ip_r, ip_i )
        ABS = tf.math.abs(comp)
        ANG = tf.math.angle(comp)

        ABS = K.relu(self.b + ABS)

        op_r = ABS * K.sin(ANG) #K.dot ??
        op_i = ABS * K.cos(ANG)

        # return single tensor in the call method
        return tf.complex(op_r, op_i)


real = tf.constant([2.25, 3.25])
imag = tf.constant([4.75, 5.75])

x = tf.complex(real, imag)

y = modrelu()(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print(sess.run(y))
```

**P.S.:** I didn't check the math so you should check it by yourself.

Comment: Why not use the add_weight method to define b values? just like the way Keras define the biases. And what is the difference between that and self.b=K.variable ?

Comment: I think you are right about add_weight method. It should be better option than K.variable. I've just made the minimal changes in the original code to make it work.

Comment: As for difference between K.variable and add_weight I only have part of the answer. If you use TensorFlow backend then each variable you create has it's own name in computational graph. If variables are created by K.variable then their names would be something like 'variable_1', 'variable_2', etc. If variables are created with add_weight then their names are 'layer_name/variable_1', 'layer_name/variable_2', etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are not coding the layer correctly, the `build` function takes a `input_shape` parameter, which you can use to initialize the weights/parameters of your layer.

You can see an example in [Keras' source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/advanced_activations.py#L109).