# Inheritance of Build in Custom Layer (super().build(input_shape))

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I was trying to understanding the concept of custom layer in tensorflow keras.
When the `Simple_dense` Layer was created without activation then the code looked like the below:

```
class SimpleDense(Layer):

    def __init__(self, units=32):
        '''Initializes the instance attributes'''
        super(SimpleDense, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        '''Create the state of the layer (weights)'''
        # initialize the weights
        w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        self.w = tf.Variable(name="kernel",
            initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                                 dtype='float32'),
            trainable=True)

        # initialize the biases
        b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
        self.b = tf.Variable(name="bias",
            initial_value=b_init(shape=(self.units,), dtype='float32'),
            trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        '''Defines the computation from inputs to outputs'''
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b
```

But when the activation function was introduced in the code then the code became:

```
class SimpleDense(Layer):

    # add an activation parameter
    def __init__(self, units=32, activation=None):
        super(SimpleDense, self).__init__()
        self.units = units
        
        # define the activation to get from the built-in activation layers in Keras
        self.activation = tf.keras.activations.get(activation)


    def build(self, input_shape):
        w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        self.w = tf.Variable(name="kernel",
            initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units), 
                                 dtype='float32'),
            trainable=True)
        #input shape is -1 as the last instance of the shape tuple actually consists 
        # the total neurons in the previous layer you can see in the model summary
        b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
        self.b = tf.Variable(name="bias",
            initial_value=b_init(shape=(self.units,), dtype='float32'),
            trainable=True)
        super().build(input_shape)


    def call(self, inputs):
        
        # pass the computation to the activation layer
        return self.activation(tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b)
```

I do understand the changes in `__init__` and `call` functions what I do not understand is that why we added `super().build(input_shape)` in the `build` function?

I have seen this in few more places where in inheriting in the build function becomes neccesity for example here([How to build this custom layer in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55863106/how-to-build-this-custom-layer-in-keras))  it is written that

> ### Be sure to call this at the end

Answer (score 1):

Back in the old days, in standalone keras, you have to call `super().build(input_shape)` in your custom build function.
And in some older versions of TF2, you have to set `self.built = True` in the custom build function instead.

But they are changing it all the time. In the latest version(v2.5.0 or later) of tensorflow, you **do not** need to do anything like these anymore. It will work the same whether or not you have called `super().build(input_shape)` in your custom build function.

Comment: My assumption of behind calling super().build(input_shape) was that we are trying to inherit something from the parent class layer. Could you please explain what was that thing that we were trying to inherit in the previous versions. Also what has changed in the newer version?

Comment: The build method will be executed at the first time when the layer is called. To achieve this, they have an attribute called `self.built` to track whether the layer is built, i.e., if `self.built` == True, the build method won't be called again. So the first thing `super().build(input_shape)` does is to set `self.built` to `True`. Second, it also stores the `input_shape` as a class attribute such that when the layer is saved and reloaded, it uses this class attribute to automatically rebuild the layer.

Comment: The reason why now you no longer need to brother with it is because it calls `super().build(input_shape)` for you just after your custom build method is called.

Comment: I notice in v2.2.0 the [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.2/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer) does not mention `self.built`. In contrast, it indeed mentions `self.built` in [v2.1.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.1/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer). Does it mean that in v2.2.0 or later, we do not need to call `super().build(input_shape)`?