# Keras: how to use dropout at train and test phase?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, dropout

Is it possible to use dropout at train and test phase in Keras?

Like described here:
https://github.com/soumith/ganhacks#17-use-dropouts-in-g-in-both-train-and-test-phase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can set `training` argument to `True` when **calling** the `Dropout` layer. In this way, dropout would be applied in both training and test phases:

```py
drp_output = Dropout(rate)(inputs, training=True)  # dropout would be active in train and test phases
```

Comment: is it possible to do this in GaussianNoise layer in Keras too?

Comment: @david Looks like in Keras you can use `keras.backend.set_learning_phase(1)` https://keras.io/backend/#set_learning_phase

Comment: But I wonder in Tensorflow if you set `training=True` in Dropout layer, will it hold after graph is converted to frozen graph or converted to coreml/tflite?

Comment: @mrgloom I think so, though I am not sure. Why do think it might not be the case?

Comment: Because frozen graph is used for inference and not for training, so I'm not sure if we can switch train / test phases in it.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers leave me slightly confused. More simply, you may find yourself doing something like this:

```
model = Model(...)
...
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
...
model.fit(...)        # invokes Dropout(training=True)
...
model.evaluate(...)   # invokes Dropout(training=False)
```

That is, when you define your model, you add `Dropout` layers with the dropout rate you want during training. The rate is not visibly varied between test and training; rather, it is declared once as a fixed value, then (invisibly) switched on/off according to the `training` parameter the layer is invoked with. See [keras.Model](https://keras.io/models/model/).

Comment: Immediate confession: this does not answer the original question, which I misread until right now. But in trying to understand how to use `Dropout`, this question ranked high. The question asks about doing something unusual - applying dropout to BOTH test and training. This answer illustrates the more normal case of applying dropout to training only.