# Keras name 'K' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to load a Keras model like so:

```
mpiotte_model = keras.models.load_model('./metadata/mpiotte-standard.model')
```

But I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-63426033cbe8> in <module>()
      2 steps = 0
      3 
----> 4 mpiotte_model = keras.models.load_model('./metadata/mpiotte-standard.model')
      5 model.set_weights(mpiotte_model.get_weights())

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core/lambda_layer.py in <lambda>(x)

NameError: Exception encountered when calling layer "lambda_3" (type Lambda).

name 'K' is not defined

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 512), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 512), dtype=float32)']
  • mask=None
  • training=False
```

I also have this line, which successfully imports:

```
from keras import backend as K
```

I am running this on a Google Colab, but I do not know how to fix the issue.

Comment: are you able to redefine the labda layer of that network? in that case you should be able to fix the issue like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845785/load-model-and-lamda-layer-in-keras

Answer (score 4):

This import is absolutely fine :

```
from keras import backend as K
```

You can try this to solve the problem :

```
mpiotte_model = keras.models.load_model('./metadata/mpiotte-standard.model', custom_objects={"K": K})
```

Comment: Thanks for this response, your method is working fine with my code!