# Errors in loading a Tensorflow .pb model: Exception encountered when calling layer "lambda_2" (type Lambda)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to load a pre-trained `saved_model.pb` model from [this](https://github.com/NJU-Jet/SR_Mobile_Quantization) repo (from the root of that repo so error is reproduceable). I want to just pass an image and visualize the resulting output image. According to some [discussions](https://github.com/NJU-Jet/SR_Mobile_Quantization/issues/11) in the issues, this code should generally work. But I get some errors.

What is the problem? How can I fix the error?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import numpy as np

model_dir = './experiment/base7_D4C28_bs16ps64_lr1e-3/best_status'
image_path = 'sample.png'

image = cv2.imread(image_path)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image = cv2.resize(image, (256, 256))
input_data = image[np.newaxis].astype(np.float32)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_dir)
output = model.predict(input_data)

output = cv2.cvtColor(output[0], cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imshow('hr', output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And error:

```
....AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\core\lambda_layer.py:327: UserWarning: solvers.networks.base7 is not loaded, but a Lambda layer uses it. It may cause errors.
  function = cls._parse_function_from_config(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Downloads\SR_Mobile_Quantization-master\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_dir)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\saving_api.py", line 238, in load_model
    return legacy_sm_saving_lib.load_model(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:/Users/Downloads/SR_Mobile_Quantization-master/solvers/networks/base7.py", line 27, in <lambda>
    clip_func = Lambda(lambda x: K.clip(x, 0., 255.))
                                 ^
NameError: Exception encountered when calling layer "lambda_2" (type Lambda).

name 'K' is not defined

Call arguments received by layer "lambda_2" (type Lambda):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=float32)
  • mask=None
  • training=None
```

Comment: It seems that there's an error importing Keras' backend from the lambda definition. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72489926/keras-name-k-is-not-defined

Comment: Did it.. didn't help